# Extra line at start when printing a pattern using while loop

Tags: python

This code prints a pattern of a series of asterisks, taking the params if the pattern is to be printed normally or inverted, and also requests the number of rows.

```
def print_pattern(rows):
    row = 0
    while row <= rows:
        output = row * "*" 
        row += 1
        print(output)

output = print_pattern(True, 3)
```

My expected output is this:

```
*
**
***
```

I instead get something like this, with an extra line on top

```
*
**
***
```

So why is this extra line left in the start?

Comment: The `inverse` parameter seems completely superfluous. Don't call the function if you don't want a result.

Comment: The ```inverse``` param will affect how the pattern is printed, it will change the number of stars in the front row

Comment: No, in the code you posted, it will simply `return None` if it's not truthy.

Comment: Hey, the other part of it is not included, as the problem was only present in this section, sorry for including that param in the first place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started `row` at 0, so your first loop iteration prints `"*"` 0 times, aka a blank line. I'd suggest starting `row` at 1.